# Is Cloning a Github repo with Git the same as cloning a repo to Github Desktop?

Tags: git, github

I was asked to clone a repo in order to run a program. When I Googled how to clone a repo the searches returned how to clone it using my Terminal (I have an M1 Mac) and a command. I tried this but got a "zsh: command not found" error, so when I kept looking through the Internet, I found instructions on how to clone the repo to my comp using Github Desktop. I was able to do this with no problems.

So, is it okay that I did this way instead of through the Terminal? Or is there something that makes the two processes different?

Comment: Github-Desktop is a self-contained GitHub App. It does not use command-line Git. It does use the same *file formats* and so on, so that it can work *with* command-line Git (though you can't really use both at the same time; IDEs are famous, or infamous, for getting confused by this sort of thing; some are better than others at it and I don't actually know how good GitHub-Desktop is at coordination, but it's generally unwise to try to mix and match like this).

Comment: To install command-line Git, either choose the Apple pre-compiled one (bundled with XCode the last time I checked, which was a long time ago), or use one of the various ports. I have used "brew", which made updating easy.